# How to store a "collection" including all models in the local-storage? (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, local-storage

I read in a big xml-file in an external `fetch()` function and this works quiet well. My question is, how could I save the filled collection to a local storage? And how could I test, if the local storage allready exists? Otherwise the `fetch()` shall be executed.
Where do I need to add code in collection? `save()`? `localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("test_storage")`?

This example shows a small piece of the code:

```
    var test_collection = Backbone.Collection.extend( .. );
    var test_collection_view = Backbone.View.extend( .. ); 


    //--------------------------------------
    // external fetch
    //--------------------------------------             
    function fetch(){
       return $.ajax({
           url: 'TestInterface.xml',
               method: 'GET',
          dataType: 'xml',
          success: function(response_xml) {

             ... //parse data to test_collection

          }//end success
       });//end ajax
    }//end fetch



    //--------------------------------------
    // Initialize
    //--------------------------------------
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.when( fetch() ).done(function() {            
            var VIEW = new test_collection_view({collection: test_collection});
        });//end when
     });//end ready
```

UPDATE:

I can also recommend this for further steps with deferred:

[Return deferred promise object and resolve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015679/return-deferred-promise-object-and-resolve-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save your collection using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
test_collection.fetch({
  success: function(collection, response) {
    // Store an array containing the attributes hash of each model
    // in the collection.
    var collectionJSON = collection.toJSON();

    // Store the collection as a JSON string.
    localStorage.setItem('collection', JSON.stringify(collectionJSON));
  }
});
```

Then you could retrieve your collection data by using:

```
var collectionString = localStorage.getItem('collection');
var collection = JSON.parse(collectionString);
```

To check if the collection is already stored:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('collection') !== null) {
  // ...
}
```

Best way to implement this is in your `fetch()` routine. First check if the collection is stored, if so return that, otherwise fetch it.